# react-day-picker year select dropdown customize max height?

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using react-day-picker in my react project and noticed the year select dropdown takes up the screen height on safari. Is there a way to add styling to this dropdown and add a max height to this dropdown? Thanks[You can see the image of dropdown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09QNf.png)

I couldn't find any div that is used to syle this dropdown

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your issue. (You can also share that code-sandbox that you have posted in image)